# PHP mysqli_stmt_num_rows does not return expected result based on query

Tags: php, mysqli

Hello StackOverflow community,

I am working on a registration system for my own use and I am trying to program it using prepared statements. Since that's recommended.

So let me explain a bit about the structure of my table.

Every user has a row called confirm which is of type enum and can be either 0 or 1.

0 - account not confirmed
1 - account confirmed

I think you can see where I'm going with this.
Simply want to check based on a query if that column is 0 or 1.

Here is a piece of my code.

```
        $sql = "SELECT username,email FROM users WHERE username=? OR email=? AND confirm=? LIMIT 1";
        $stmt = mysqli_stmt_init($conx);
        if(!mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt,$sql)) exit(mysqli_error($conx));
        else {
            $confirm = 0;
            mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt,"ssi",$usernameEmail,$usernameEmail,$confirm);
            mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
            $count = mysqli_stmt_num_rows($stmt);
            if($count == 1) exit("Please confirm your account before logging in.");
            else exit("Ok continue ...");
```

In my Database I have 1 confirmed account and one not confirmed account to be able to test both cases.

PHP keeps on going to the else line even tho the account is not confirmed.

The user can use either his or her email or username to log in.
I am rather new at when it comes to prepared statements.
Sorry if i didn't nail the formatting right away. My first post on stack overflow :)

Your help would be much appreciated!
Cheers,
Andi

Comment: What user record is it returning? Are you sure it is getting a record?

Comment: Hello Mr Glass, it returns 0 when i try to echo out the count. even tho i know for sure i have one confirmed and 1 not confirmed account in my database.

Answer (score 0):

Your query needs a little help with formatting to select the correct record

```
// put parens around your OR 
$sql = "SELECT username,email FROM users WHERE (username=? OR email=?) AND confirm=? LIMIT 1";
```

And, since your `confirmed` column is an `enum` you can't use `i` in your `bind`. Your `bind` needs to use 'sss' instead of 'ssi'.

```
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt,"sss",$usernameEmail,$usernameEmail,$confirm);
```

Comment: I already tried adding round brackets just like that but it does not make any difference.

Comment: @Andi, whether you are currently getting the output you want right now or now, you need those parens for your query to work correctly in the future.

Comment: also tried changing the query to this: $sql = "SELECT username,email FROM users WHERE confirm=? AND (username=? OR email=?) LIMIT 1";

Comment: Changed "i"to "s" $sql = "SELECT username,email FROM users WHERE (username=? OR email=?) AND confirm=?";
   $stmt = mysqli_stmt_init($conx);
   if(!mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt,$sql)) exit(mysqli_error($conx));
   else {
    $confirm = 0;
    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt,"sss",$usernameEmail,$usernameEmail,$confirm);
    mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
    $count = mysqli_stmt_num_rows($stmt);
    if($count == 1) exit("Please confirm your account before logging in.");
    else echo $count; still returns 0

Comment: What happens when you pass strings as parameters in your `bind` instead of your variables? BTW, it looks like you've got `$usernameEmail` in your `bind` twice now.

Comment: Im not sure you are allowed to pass anything else in your binding statements but variables. I've got the $usernameEmail twice because you could you either your username or your email for logging in. Shouldn't i pass it twice? I have reprogrammed the algorithm and now it seems to be working. I will update my code so you can see. I'd rather prefer the first version tho, because it is much shorter.

Comment: @Andi, I'm suggesting strings **only for debugging this issue**.  If you hardcode the values you want for testing, and it returns the correct row, then you know it is a problem with your variables and not your SQL statements.

Comment: I have hardcoded values in the query itself, still returns 0. However it looks like i do not have enough rep to edit my own question. I wanted to post the second attempt which seems to be working fine.

Comment: Thank you for all the effort you put in helping me :)